# Favoriting/Subclipping with Long Clips in Timeline in FCPX

Tags: software, editing, final-cut-pro, final-cut-pro-x

I'm editing a project where I have 5 very long clips.  I'm going through, favorite-ing the good portions ("subclipping" per se) and then organizing my clips from those subclips.

A problem I'm running into however, is that I would like to have finer control over my in and out points, so I would like to open my long clips in the timeline, so I can use the scrubber over a larger area.  But when the clip is "opened in timeline" I can't favorite portions of it.

Is there any workaround to this?  Or a different solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event browser needs to be in filmstrip view for this to work. Press [⌥⌘1]  Then you can Zoom in [⌘+] or out [⌘-] to whatever granularity you like.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use JKL to scrub in the Viewer, directly in the Event Library. Press L to play forward at 1x. Press another time to play at 2x and so forth.
Press K to stop playback.
L plays backwards. Multiple invocations result in faster playback.
Hold down K and press L to go one frame forward, K + J to go one frame backward.

Maybe you can give it a go and see if that work out for you. If not go with Jason Conrad's suggestion.